# How silverlight code gets debugged

Tags: silverlight

As an .xap file is added in the web project which runs at client side, then can anyone please explain how are we able to debug the silverlight client side code?

Answer (score 3):

If you are running the web server built into Visual Studio then Visual Studio is both hosting the web server and running the web client. This means you are able to debug both the client and server side code.

If you are using IIS to serve the site then you are still running the web client within Visual Studio.

As long has you have the "Debuggers" option set on the web project you will be able to set break points and step through the code.

Answer (score 0):

In the  web project properties, under ‘web’ tab all way at the bottom, there is a group called ‘Debuggers’, make sure you have Silverlight check box is checked. By checking the Silverlight check box you will be able to debug the client side code.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. That still does not answer completely to what i need to ask. I'll be posting my comment on that in a day or two as soon as I get free.

Comment: Also, you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there). It will help you get more answers.